# How to execute it using pre sql and post sql in Informatica

Tags: informatica

ETL_JOB_ID:- There will be one ID for one workflow; it means WF_X_STG will have 1 and WF_Y_STG will have 2 always

ETL_JOB_NAME:- This will be the workflow name.

ETL_LOAD_PROCESS_NUMBER:- This will be batch number; means number of execution on any respective day. Suppose if workflow is running every 1 hour, this will be having 24 entries per day.

JOB_RUNSTART_TS:- This will be sessionstarttime

JOB_RUN_STATUS:- This will be STARTED or IN_PROGRESS and later will be updated to COMPLETED and FAILED based on outcome.

JOB_RUNEND_TS:- This will be NULL initially and later will be updated to CURRENT_TIME which is the end time of the object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask and modify your question with what specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this framework out: http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html

Or just use Metadata to fetch what you need directly from Informatica DB.